# Kendo Chart Databinding - Local Json Data with schema

Tags: html, asp.net, json, charts, kendo-ui

I have below json returned data and like to bind in the Kendo Chart

```js
var stockReportingList= {
"StockDetails" : [
{"Total" : 230, "Sold" : 200, "Unsold" : 30,  "Month" : "Jan 2016" },
{"Total" : 550, "Sold" : 430, "Unsold" : 220,  "Month" : "Feb 2016" },
{"Total" : 200, "Sold" : 100, "Unsold" : 100,  "Month" : "Mar 2016" }
]
}
```

below is my script to plot chart

```js
$("#MarketStockChart").kendoChart({
dataSource : {
data : stockReportingList
},
seriesDefaults : {
type : "column",
stack: true
},

series : [{
field : "Sold"
name : "Sold"
data : stockReportingList
},
{
field : "UnSold"
name : "UnSold"
data : stockReportingList`enter code here`
}],

valueAxis : {
labels : {
format : "{0}",
visible : true,
position : "top"
}

},

categoryAxis :
{
field : "Month"
}
});
```

The Kendo Chart not displaying properly, Can you please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had make lots of corrections in your code to make your charts work.

Below is your modified code:

```
 <script>
  var stockReportingList = {
     "StockDetails": [{
         "Total": 230,
         "Sold": 200,
         "Unsold": 30,
         "Month": "Jan 2016"
     }, {
         "Total": 550,
         "Sold": 430,
         "Unsold": 220,
         "Month": "Feb 2016"
     }, {
         "Total": 200,
         "Sold": 100,
         "Unsold": 100,
         "Month": "Mar 2016"
     }]
 };

 $(function() {
     $("#MarketStockChart").kendoChart({
         dataSource: {
             data: stockReportingList.StockDetails
         },
         seriesDefaults: {
             type: "column",
             stack: true
         },

         series: [{
             field: "Sold",
             name: "Sold"
         }, {
             field: "Unsold",
             name: "Unsold"
         }],

         valueAxis: {
             labels: {
                 format: "{0}",
                 visible: true,
                 position: "top"
             }
         },
         categoryAxis: {
             field: "Month"
         }
     });
 });
  </script>
```

Few changes I am mentioning which I had to make:

- I passed stockReportingList.StockDetails as dataSource.
- Corrected spelling of Unsold in series. It was not matching with your datasource key.
- Wrapped whole code in  $(function() {...}) to ensure that DOM has
  been loaded.
- Removed DataSource option from series as it was not required.

Below is live working example for your code:

http://dojo.telerik.com/epOVe

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I checked that it is working in the link you have provided, but when i try the same in my website after the link button click, chart not plotted and in the y axis there is no relevant data, displaying something 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, there is nothing in x axis...

Comment: just copy my code and try to run. May be you are still missing something.

Comment: Thank you... It is working... There was issue in my json return... So i just converted the return value as JavaScript object.. Then it worked...

Your help appreciated.

Comment: var objStockList = JSON.parse(stockReportingList)

Then i have used the objStockList.StockDetails in the DataSource.